# Is there a function that filter positive values x = f(x), and return zero for all negative values?

Tags: functions

I'm searching for f that will comply this definition :

x = f(x) where x is a non-negative integer .. x >= 0

0 = f(x) where x is a negative integer .. x < 0

Comment: Welcome! You want`Clip`.

Comment: `UnitStep` and `HeavisideTheta`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  What does $x = f(x)$ mean?  Is it an equation that you want to solve?  Did you mean to use a different variable than $x$ somewhere?  Are you talking about $x$ being positive or $f(x)$ being positive?  What do you mean by "natural"?  There are no negative natural numbers.  Voting to close until question gets formulated precisely.  Looking at the answers and comments it's clear that at least half of them is not what you want as people are interpreting the question in different ways.  Explaining clearly will save time for everyone.

Comment: Perhaps `f[x_Integer] := Piecewise[{{x, x >= 0}}]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build your filter with `UnitStep`, `Chop`, or `HeavisideTheta` as mentioned in the comments to your question,

```
f1[x_] := x UnitStep[x]
f2[x_] := Clip[x, {0, x}]
f3[x_] := x HeavisideTheta[x]
```

All of these will give the same values when given the same arguments, but what of the cost? We don't want to be programmers who "know the value of everything but the cost of nothing" (Alan Perlis, 1982; [#55](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Alan_Perlis)), so let's look at some timings.

```
f0[x_] := x (* baseline *)
args = Range[-500000, 500000];
test[f_] := AbsoluteTiming[f /@ args;][[1]]
Grid[{
    {"x\[Function]x", test[f0]},
    {UnitStep, test[f1]},
    {Clip, test[f2]},
    {HeavisideTheta, test[f3]}},
  Alignment -> {Left, Right}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image: grid]

It is something of a surprise to me that `Clip` is the fastest. Before I did the timings, I would have put my money on `UnitStep`, which is the slowest by a hair.

#### Update

I have updated the code to incorporated the corrections pointed out by 2012rcampion.

Comment: Your definition for `test` should be `test[f_, args_]` or you should call it without `args`.  (Also your range is not symmetric, -500k to +50k)

Comment: Also if you use `Clip[x, {0, \[Infinity]}]` (what I would have used) `Clip` becomes the slowest; but `Clip[x, {0, x}]` is faster than all four.

Comment: @2012rcampion. +1. Thanks for pointing out the errors.

Comment: I'd like to point out that using `Clip` in vectorized way i.e, `Clip[args, {0, \[Infinity]}]` is 400(!) times faster (at least on my machine).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
f[x_] := x*HeavisideTheta[x];
```

Have a look here:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

yields

[image]